# ExtJS chart for series with independent arguments

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, series

I've a question regarding ExtJS charts:
Is it possible to use series in one chart, which don't share all arguments?

I would like to draw two series based on such data store:

```
data: [
   { arg: 1, val1: 11 },
   { arg: 2, val2: 23 },
   { arg: 3, val1: 12, val2: 24 },
   { arg: 4, val1: 13 },
   { arg: 5, val2: 25 },
]
```

I would like to get two independent lines for that poins only:
first for (1,11)(3,12)(4,13) 
and the second for (2,23)(3,24)(5,25).

I observe, that ExtJS sets the missing values with 0 (that creates extra points)
or breaks the chart when I set the missing values to false (than some points are missing).

Look at that fiddle to have visualization of my problem: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12jo

My question: how to draw those two lines independently? Perhaps should I use two stores? or use separate arguments (like fields: [arg1, val1, arg2, val2] )?

Regards,
Annie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to create separate data stores and assign them to the series.
Thank you sencha forum!
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?307514-Chart-for-series-with-independent-arguments&p=1123314&viewfull=1#post1123314